# While setting cell value in excel using apache poi in selenium I am getting null point exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

This is selenium code using apache Poi where I am reading a file value from excel and opening a link while writing a string value in excel file its giving me null point exception. can you tell me what is wrong ?

on last line I am getting errors, the lines are:-

```
sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(2).setCellValue(linkLocatin);

File src = new File ("C:\\Sandeep\\Selenium\\automationproject1\\Testdata.xlsx");
```

My all code:-

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);

        XSSFWorkbook wb =new XSSFWorkbook (fis);

        XSSFSheet sheet1 =wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowcount= sheet1.getLastRowNum();
        XSSFCell cel;

         //System.out.println ("Test data is " + data0);
        System.out.println ("rowncount is = "+ rowcount);

     for (int i=1; i<= rowcount;i++)
        {

        //Set browser profile and then get link from excel
        FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();

         prof.setPreference("media.windows-media-foundation.enabled", false);
         prof.setPreference("media.directshow.enabled", false);
         prof.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
         prof.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Sandeep\\Selenium\\automationproject1\\Download1");
         prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
         prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "audio/x-mpeg-3"); 
         prof.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
         prof.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);

        String data0 = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue(); 
        System.out.println(data0);

        // open the link in browser         
        driver.get(data0);                  
        WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download the recording"));
        String linkLocatin = link.getAttribute("href");
        sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(2).setCellValue(linkLocatin);
```

While setting up string value in excel it's showing null point exception ..W

Comment: Could either the Row or the Cell be null? What happens if you do "check if this exists and create if not" code around the Row and Cell access?

Comment: Make sure String linkLocatin is not printing null value.

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(2).setCellValue(linkLocatin); only updates the excel cell if it has some data in that cell previously.so workaround is fill the cells with dummy value and let this method update that value.